# DRF transmit errors through functions

Tags: python, django, error-handling, django-rest-framework

*I know that this question may be already asked or be very obvious but I cannot find anything about it.*

Let's say we have this method in `views.py`:

```
def my_api_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        return HttpResponse(other_function())
    else:
        return HttpResponse("{UERR:%s}" % {UERR_POST_REQUEST_EXPECTED})
```

where `other_function()` is a function in another file in another directory outside of Django app:

```
def other_function():
    a = function1()
    b = function2()
    return function3(a,b)
```

**Question**: If something goes wrong in `other_function()`, `function1()`, `function2()` or `function3(a,b)` how do we make our view to return an HttpResponse with an error? For example, if `function1()` access an unavailable resource.

Comment: You already have an error case in your view. Just add another one. Call `other_function` and evaluate the result or let it raise an error that you catch in your view. Also, how is this related to DRF?

Answer (score 0):

An `HttpResponse` with an error is usually just a response with a 400 status code (indicating an error with the clients request, not your server)

```
def my_api_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        return HttpResponse(other_function())
    else:
        return HttpResponse("{UERR:%s}" % {UERR_POST_REQUEST_EXPECTED}, status=400)
```

If you're using rest framework, the convention is to return `rest_framework.response.Response` though.

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
def my_api_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        return Response(other_function())
    else:
        return Response("{UERR:%s}" % {UERR_POST_REQUEST_EXPECTED}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```